# Using multiprocessing pool with psycopg2 ThreadedConnectionPool

Tags: python, postgresql, multiprocessing, psycopg2

While using ThreadedConnectionPool from psycopg2.pool, I'm trying to get multiple connections from the pool and use them with multiprocessing. I've created the following class to create a static connection pool and another helper class to use with context.

```
import psycopg2
import os
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

class Database:
    __connection_pool = None
    
    @staticmethod
    def initialize(**kwargs):
        Database.__connection_pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(
                                                    minconn=1,
                                                    maxconn=15,
                                                    **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def get_connection(cls):
        try:
            return Database.__connection_pool.getconn()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
    
    @classmethod
    def return_connection(cls,connection):
        Database.__connection_pool.putconn(connection,close=False)
        
    @classmethod
    def close_all_connections(cls):
        if not Database.connection_closed():
            Database.__connection_pool.closeall()
        else:
            return "Connection Already Closed!"
    
    @classmethod
    def connection_closed(cls):
        try:
            return Database.__connection_pool.closed
        except:
            return True
        
class CursorFromPool:
    
    '''
    Wrapper class to connect to PostgresDB    
    '''

    def __init__():
        self.key=key
        self.connection = None
        self.cursor = None

    def __enter__(self):
        '''
        using the class with "with"
        call a new connection from the pool
        '''
        self.connection = Database.get_connection()
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        '''
        commit the cursor and put the connection
        back to the connection pool
        '''
        if exc_val is not None:
            self.connection.rollback()
        else:
            self.cursor.close()
            self.connection.commit()
        Database.return_connection(self.connection)
        
    def get_open_conn(self):
        self.connection = Database.get_connection()
        if self.connection is not None: 
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            return self.cursor

    def put_conn(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.commit()

    def close_open_connection(self):
        Database.return_connection(self.connection)
        
    def connection_closed(self):
        if self.connection is not None:
            if self.connection.closed == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return "No connections established"
```

The above classes work fine and I can retrieve individual connections from each of them while calling get_open_conn() and I'm able to exhaust all connections from the pool. While using the following code in multiprocessing I get the following error, which says connection already closed. For simplicity sake I'm calling the same function over and over again to upload the same data to table in db.

```
def clean(skiprows=None):

    df_flags = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
    data_list = [tuple(row) for row in df_flags.itertuples(index=False)] 
    
    start = time.time()
    with CursorFromPool() as cursor:
        psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor,'INSERT INTO db_name.table_name VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)',data)
        print(cursor.statusmessage)
    end = time.time()
    print(start-end)
    return True

Database.initialize(*db_args_passed_here*)
skiper = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
with Pool(processes = 4) as pool:
    pool.map(clean,skiper)
    
if Database.connection_closed == False:
    Database.close_all_connections()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/upload_to_db/helper.py", line 53, in clean
    psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor,'INSERT INTO db_name.table_name VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)',data_list)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1198, in execute_batch
    cur.execute(b";".join(sqls))
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/mnt/upload_to_db/helper.py", line 54, in clean
    print(cursor.statusmessage)
  File "/mnt/utils/ConnectionPool.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.connection.rollback()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    pool.map(clean,skiper)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Comment: That's right, If you look at the Database class, I have a function defined called return_connection. If you track it down to CursorFromPool __exit__ method, its using return_connection to exit the with context.

Comment: Any luck with this? I have faced the same problem and solved it by creating a new connection on entry(__init__()) and closing on exit. But, upon heavy load, some processes get stuck while creating a new connection.

Comment: Nope, I had to use the traditional method to create a connection and use it and pass it to multiprocess module. I couldn't figure out how to secure n number of connections and use those.