# How to increase acknowledgement deadline time without using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing, google-cloud-pubsub

Currently, I am modifying the acknowledgment deadline time as described in the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull_with_lease_management). The issue with the multiprocessing module is, some of the typical libraries require special treatment when used in multiprocessing environment. e.g.
 1. [you cant use psycopg2 connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164971/using-multiprocessing-pool-with-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool), either you need to create a new connection for every operation or pass the connection from main thread.
2. logging module needs [multiprocessing Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) and [QueueListener](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.QueueListener) in order to work with multiprocessing.
 3. even GCP storage client needs to be instantiated inside each process(which is not ideal).
**So, is there any alternate way to modify acknowledgment deadline time without using multiprocessing module?**

EDIT:

1. In multiprocessing, if the target function uses psycopg2 then we need to create a DB connection during each database operation (which is expensive and not ideal). you can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164971/using-multiprocessing-pool-with-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool) SO question for more details.
2. if you use google cloud storage client then you need to create an instance [inside the target function](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html#example-usage)(which is again not ideal).
   if anyone doing these operations much more frequently(like we do), will obviously look for an alternative approach to increase ack deadline. [This (official doc) way of modifying ack deadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull_with_lease_management) has some cost.

EDIT 2: 
This [GitHub repo](https://github.com/janmejaya-nanda/pub-sub-worker) contains my current implementation ( which pulls a message and updates ack deadline time).

Comment: I do not really understand the use case. Could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: what's the issue with the multiprocessing module?

Comment: @vitooh my code snippet will be almost similar to the doc below. instead of `time.sleep` I have my own function. for more clarity let me add some pseudo code.
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull_with_lease_management

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere please check edit for the issue with multiprocessing.

Comment: I can't comment on the multiprocessing aspect, but I can for the python Cloud Pub/Sub library. The library expects the subscriber client to be continuously running because there's several threads in the background that do work like automatically modacking the messages. Alternatively, you can manually construct a ModAck RPC yourself using this method: https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/911829d85c6ec36a87b873cbfe34497b1a493dde/google/pubsub_v1/services/subscriber/client.py#L838